# Python: “Assertion failed: ptr < end”

Tags: python, assert, glpk

I am running a couple of Nested For Loops and in them some If-Else conditions. I have not used `assert` anywhere in the code. After running a while, the program throws up an Assertion Error:

```
Assertion failed: ptr < end

Error detected in file ..\src\bflib\sgf.c at line 146
```

This is a part of `GNU Linear Programming Kit` which got imported from another library, `COBRApy`, I imported.

I have tried the Try-Catch setup which didn't work. Also tried running the code with the `-O` flag, but that didn't work too. My hunch is that I am not able to catch the exception thrown by the library. How can I do that? Any other suggestions?

Comment: The error tells you exactly where an assertion has failed. Obviously it is not your code, so it is either a problem in `COBRApy` code (e.g. incorrect `glpk` usage) or in `glpk` itself. Your best bet would be to contact COBRApy devs.

Comment: The code is not raising a Python exception.  It is calling [`assert(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert).  Since that calls [`abort(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort), it is not reasonably possible to catch.  You could theoretically implement a signal handler for SIGABRT which calls [`longjmp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/longjmp), but this is a rather insane idea in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having the same problem as well when using GLPK in combination with COBRApy on a computer running Linux. GLPK would work fine most of the time, but when performing large numbers of optimizations I would always get this error eventually. The problem seems to be in GLPK, not in COBRApy, but unfortunately I was never able to resolve it.

My only recommendation is to use one of the many other solvers that are supported by COBRApy. If you are in some way connected to academia, [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com), [Mosek](http://www.mosek.com) and [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/) all offer free licenses. Specifically, I have found both Gurobi and Mosek to work perfectly with COBRApy and the process of installing and obtaining licenses is really easy.

If you find a way to use any other solver, there is really no reason to use GLPK (other than perhaps convenience).